# TypeError: Key id must be a string or a number

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to delete a `key` value from a list.So i created a method in my class like this:

```
def deleteEmployee(self, employee):
    employee_to_Delete = ndb.Key(Employee, employee)
    if employee_to_delete in self.employees:
        idx=self.employees.index(employee_to_delete)
        del self.employees[idx]
        self.put()
```

and then in the method where i am calling this method, i have something like

```
class DeleteEmployeeHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    employee_name = self.request.get('employee_name')
    employee=Employee.get_by_id(employee_name)
    emp_dept=employee.department
    dept=Department.get_or_insert(emp_dept)
    dept.deleteEmployee(employee)
    employee.delete()
```

but I get the error message

`TypeError: key id must be a string or a number`. Can someone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: on the `employee_to_Delete = ndb.Key(Employee, employee)` line

Comment: It seems that you need to say `dept.deleteEmployee(employee_name)` instead of `dept.deleteEmployee(employee)`.

Comment: When i try this, i get a new error message saying `NameError: Global name 'employee_to_delete' is not defined.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`employee` is an instance of the `Employee` class, and you're passing that as the second parameter to `ndb.Key`. But the error message tells you exactly what's wrong: that parameter should be a string or an int, not an instance.

But, since you actually have the instance already, you don't need to construct a new Key: the employee object already has one, which you can use to delete.

```
employee_to_Delete = employee.key
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is from [google's datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass), not from Python's list.

You call `ndb.Key(Employee, employee)` and my guess is the `employee` you pass in is wrong type.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by wrong type? because when i change the line `employee_to_delete = ndb.key(Employee, employee)` to `employee_to_delete=ndb.Key(Employee, employee.key)` i get the error message `TypeError: Key id must be a string or a number; received Employee(key=Key('Employee', 'Alex Brown'), age=45, date_of_employment=datetime.date(2014, 4,
 28), department=u'Other Charges', employee_name=u'Alex Brown')
INFO     2014-04-28 10:07:50,878 module.py:627] default: "POST /deleteEmp HTTP/1.1" 500 -`